# How to split lines from a grep on a file?

Tags: linux, bash

Given Employee.txt,

```
PD:198801221:Jason:Jason@gmail.com
PU:19941029:Tan:tan@gmail.com
PS:19960601:May:may@gmail.com
```

and a form,

```
echo -n "Enter BirthDate:";read bdate
grep "$bdate" Employee.txt
echo "Employee name (auto display):"
echo "Employee email (auto display):"
```

which takes an employee birth date and displays the name and email based on the input file.

For example, if I input in the BirthDate as `19941029`, the result I get from the file is `PU:19941029:Tan:tan@gmail.com`

The above script displays the entire line.

How can I separate the line into the auto display name and email fields?

Comment: Is this a simplfied version of a real-world problem, or is it a learning exercise from coursework or ?? Basically, you're using the wrong tool. Good luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pipe the grep output through [cut](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/cut.1.html) and pick up the fields you want.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
set -eu

echo -n "Enter BirthDate: "
read -r bdate

found=$(grep "$bdate" Employee.txt)
name=$(echo "$found" | cut -d: -f 3)
email=$(echo "$found" | cut -d: -f 4)

echo "Employee name (auto display): $name"
echo "Employee email (auto display): $email"
```

This is fairly simplistic and breaks if your fields contain separator characters (colons in this case). In that case you should get a CSV reader.

Answer (score 2):

You can use IFS to read the input into 4 variables

```
echo -n "Enter BirthDate:";read bdate

match=$(grep "$bdate" Employee.txt)
IFS=':' read -r first second third fourth <<<$match


echo "Employee name (auto display):" $third
echo "Employee email (auto display):" $fourth
```

References

https://bash.cyberciti.biz/guide/$IFS

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/209123/understanding-ifs-read-r-line